# How to avoid repetition of .then() and .catch() after $http requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, dry

I have a simple userAPI service in my angular app:

```
app.service('userAPI', function ($http) {
this.create = function (user) {
    return $http
        .post("/api/user", { data: user })
        .then(function (promise) { return promise.data })
        .catch(function (error) { return error.data })
}

this.read = function (user) {
    return $http
        .get("/api/user/" + user.id)
        .then(function (promise) { return promise.data })
        .catch(function (error) { return error.data })
}

this.update = function (user) {
    return $http
        .patch("/api/user/" + user.id, { data: user })
        .then(function (promise) { return promise.data })
        .catch(function (error) { return error.data })
}

this.delete = function (user) {
    return $http
        .delete("/api/user/" + user.id)
        .then(function (promise) { return promise.data })
        .catch(function (error) { return error.data })
}
})
```

As you can see, i am repeating same .then() and .catch() functions after each of my $http requests. Ho can i avoid this repitition according to DRY principle?

Comment: I don't see what those callbacks do...

Comment: Why not just catch the error in the controller (or wherever you use the `userAPI` service)?

Comment: Also, more importantly, why aren't you using __[$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)__ for this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write the functions once and apply them to each callback in the service?

Something like:

```
app.service('userAPI', function ($http) {
    var success = function (response) { return response.data; },
        error = function (error) { return error.data; };

    this.create = function (user) {
        return $http
          .post("/api/user", { data: user })
          .then(success, error);
    }
    this.read = function (user) {
      return $http
        .get("/api/user/" + user.id)
        .then(success, error);
    };
    this.update = function (user) {
      return $http
        .patch("/api/user/" + user.id, { data: user })
        .then(success, error);
    };
    this.delete = function (user) {
      return $http
        .delete("/api/user/" + user.id)
        .then(success, error);
    };
});
```

Also note you can use `then(successcallback, errorcallback, notifycallback)` to shorten your code even further than using then/catch.

Comment: This is the best and most you can do for such async thing...!

Comment: To keep the error on the fail path, `error.data` should be thrown, not returned.

Comment: Or maybe it's `return $q.reject(error.data);` with $q. *confusing*

Comment: What Roamer said is correct - also note that `.then(success, error)`  does something different from `.then(success).catch(error)`.