# How to DRY http success and error functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Say I have more than `100` requests in my application. It would be cumbersome and time consuming to write  as many `success` and `error` functions to handle `response`.

At the moment I do like this:

```js
angular
  .module('mahanApp')
  .service('HttpService', function($http) {
      // Get all  name
      function getNames() {
        return $http.get('/data/names/')
      }

      return {
        getNames: getNames
      }
      .controller('NameController', function NameController(
        HttpService) {
        var ctrl = this;

        // Fetch all templates name;
        HttpService.getNames().then(
          function success(response) {
            ctrl.names = response.data;
          },
          function error(response) {});
      })
  });
```

As you see, it is a lot of work to write so many callback functions for `100+` requests. I wonder if it is possible to avoid doing so.

There is [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667147/how-to-avoid-repetition-of-then-and-catch-after-http-requests) that suggests to do like the code below.

```js
angular
  .module('mahanApp')
  .service('HttpService', function($http) {

    var success = function(response) {
        return response.data;
      },
      error = function(error) {
        return error.data;
      };

    // Get all  name
    function getNames() {
      return $http.get('/data/names/').then(success, error)
    }

    return {
      getNames: getNames
    }
    .controller('NameController', function NameController(
      HttpService) {
      var ctrl = this;

    })
  });
```

In the `NameController`, I used `ctrl.names = HttpService.getNames()`. But `ctrl.names` is `undefined`.  How to use the `HttpService.getNames()` in `NameController`?

**Update:**

A few people has commented to resolve the promise.

```js
HttpService.getNames().then(function success(result) {
  ctrl.names = result;
})
```

It works. However, I still write `100+` functions to resolve the promise.

**How to avoid repeating the `success` and `error` functions or if possible the whole `then()` method?**

Comment: Your second approach is the right way - just use `HttpService.getNames()` inside your `NameController` - what's the issue/error you get if you do that?

Comment: `mahanService.getNames()` will return a promise.. you need to resolve the promise to assign it to a variable.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Ok. I used `ctrl.names = httpService.getNames()`. But `ctrl.names` is `undefined`.

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar. I do not know how to resolve it. If you know, it would be great that you write your solution as an answer.

Comment: If your promise is pending(not resolved yet), I think you only have to call .then(function(result) {} after that, this way you can assign the result of the promise and not the promise itself

Comment: `HttpService.getNames()` will return a Promise, you need to call `HttpService.getNames().then(res => myVar = res)` in your controller

Comment: You can use `.then()` as previously mentioned or with ES8 you can use `ctrl.names = await httpService.getNames()`...for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Thanks everyone. It works now. But I still repeat codes.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to sum up the discussion and some ways you can remove duplication:

First of all, your second approach is the right direction to re-using a function in your controllers.

A classical approach would be this:

```
return {
  getNames: getNames
}
.controller('NameController', function NameController(
  HttpService) {
  var ctrl = this;
  HttpService.getNames().then(function(res) { ctrl.names = res; } );
})
```

Note that you can even extract this more if all your calls are following the same format, for example you could:

```
// utility function that loads something into your controller
var load = function(request, ctrl, prop) {
    request.then(function(res) { ctrl[prop] = res; } 
};

// this way you can have many of requests with minimal code
load(HttpService.getNames, ctrl, 'names');
load(HttpService.getBooks, ctrl, 'books');
load(HttpService.getThings, ctrl, 'things');
...
```

Alternatively, if you can use ES2017 in your project (e.g. your code is transpiled) you can simplify using some of the new features without the need of an additional function:

```
// Using promise all will assure these are all fetched asynchronously in respect to one another
Promise.all([
    async () => ctrl.names = await HttpService.getNames(),
    async () => ctrl.books = await HttpService.getBooks(),
    async () => ctrl.things = await HttpService.getThings()
]);
```

Finally, you might actually want to parameterize your request so that you have just one:

```
// Get all
function getAll(what) {
  return $http.get('/data/' + what).then(success, error)
}
```

Then you don't need to have a different method for each type, you'll just do:

```
getAll('names');
getAll('books');
...
```